# What kind of repairs are prudent for a ridge board damaged by a falling tree?

Tags: repair, wood, roof, framing

The limbs of [the tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE7Kp.jpg) punctured the roof in at least two spots, so we're already looking at repairs. Upon closer inspection within the attic, I noticed that the ridge beam is just slightly splintered near one of the puncture spots close to the apex.

*Click on photo for full size*
[image: Splintered Ridge Beam]

I'm working on documenting everything to present to the insurance claims adjuster. I've dealt with tree on roof damage before; my previous experience was not great so I'd just like to get all my ducks in a row regarding what must be repaired.

**How important is it that this fractured ridge beam gets repaired? Does the whole beam need to be replaced, or can it be "patched"?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is a 1x board, I take it this is a ridge board and not a true beam. If this is in an attic and there are ceiling joists below the rafters making a triangular structure, the ridge board has little structural value, it just serves to tie the rafters together, it does not support any vertical loads. In that case, nail/gluing patch blocks on each side will suffice as a repair.

If this is a true load bearing beam, (unlikely since it appears to be a 1x board) it would have needed to be replaced in it's entirety unless a licensed engineer could design a proper repair to the beam.

Comment: I would also closely examine where the other end of the rafters tie in to make sure they are still firmly attached.